# How can I get inlineblock to indent on safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am trying to indent the text from an inline block on safari. It only indents in chrome.

I have tried using margin left. This works in chrome but in safari i have to adjust the margin-left to another number for them to look the same.

I tried the text-indent and the inline-block is not wrapping properly now.

html

```
        <nav>
    <ul>


      <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
      <li type="checkbox" class="sub">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <a href="#" >Profile</a>


        <!-- Begin-->

             <ul class="submenu">
          <li >
            <a  target = "box">Profiles</a>

          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>


        <!-- end-->
      <li class="sub">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <a href="#" >Logs</a>


        <!-- Begin-->

             <ul class="submenu">
             <li >
            <a   target = "box" >View Logs</a>

          </li>
          <li >
            <a   target = "box" >Testing a long test</a>

          </li>

        </ul>
      </li>

      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS in chrome

```
 nav .submenu a {

 *zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 122px;
  margin-left: 55px;

  padding: 3px 1px 3px 0px;
```

}

CSS in safari

```
 nav .submenu a {

 *zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;
 display: inline-block;
 max-width: 122px;
  margin-left: 65px;

  padding: 3px 1px 3px 0px;

 }
```

I tried putting important on the variables to see anything overrides it too and that didn't help them look the same.

I also tried

text-indent: 50px;

Answer (score 1):

Make a table with no content and put it ahead of your text.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="65px"> <!--this is the indent, don't forget to style it so it becomes invisible.--></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: so put that before the text? its still not indenting.

Comment: @user6535413 you actually have to make a table and put your text in it. It will work.